# What is the connection between the language (of some formal grammar) and algebra on the words of this language?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, formal-languages, formal-grammar

Formal language is the set of words that are generated from production rules. There are 2 kind of operations on such language:

1. application of production rules to generate new (grammatically valid) word from the existing words;
2. application of inference rules to generate new (grammatically and semantically valid) word (it can be called sentence as well in some settings) from the existing (grammatically and semantically valid) words.

So - there are 2 kind of operations: 1) application of production rules; 2) application of inference rules (subset of production rules?).

My question is - how those grammatical/inferential operations are connected to the algebra? Does the grammar of the formal language define special algebra of words? Are the operations of this algebra connected to the grammatical/inferential operations of the language? Is algebra used for modelling the formal language?

I feel that there is some connection but I am really confused.

**Maybe term algebra is the answer?**

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. It seems like your 1. corresponds to a formal language, and your 2. is a proof system. Then you want to know how these are connected to algebra, and there are many possible avenues for answer. If you can explain what kind of algebra you're thinking of, I can possibly answer

Comment: Maybe term algebra is the answer? Are there any other relevant algebras? I know formal grammars, logic (proof theory, algebraic semantics and semantics) quite well, but I wonder - are there purely algebraic attempts to characterize the words in language? I mean - words can be quite complex combinatorial structures (think of some theorem that is completely expanded in Isabelle/HOL base logic) and can algebra be used to discover, describe or otherwise research such interesting words that can emerge in language?

Comment: My intention is to try to apply algebraic methods for the research of complex systems. The HOL language (e.g. TPTP language) is the most general language in which we can write every possible property of environment and every possible message among agents (parts of complex systems). So - maybe we can describe the exchange of messages among agents of complex system or describe the interaction among agents of complex system - maybe we can describe this in some logical or formal language. And the we can consider such language as algebra. And hence - we can use algebra for research of...

Comment: ... complex adaptive dynamic systems in the most general sense. Currently complex system theory uses mathematical analysis and considers only the numerical properties of environment and agents. But there can be discrete, logical complex systems as well - e.g. communicating agents. And analysis is not apropriate for that.

Comment: Not to sure if I get your question right, but maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic_to_B%C3%BCchi_automaton) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) goes the right direction?